# How to animate a UICollectionView cell selection

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

What does the `animated` argument of these methods of `UICollectionView` do:

- ```swift
  selectItem(at indexPath: IndexPath?, animated: Bool, scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition)`
  ```
- ```swift
  deselectItem(at indexPath: IndexPath, animated: Bool)
  ```

I know I can use the `UICollectionViewLayout` object to animate changes.  I also know that I can use `didSelect` and `didDeselect` methods of the `UICollectionViewDelegate` to get the selected cell and apply animations.  But I can't find any information about how the above `animated` argument affects animations.  Does it affect the layout animations in any way?  My goal is to create a `UICollectionView` subclass and allow the consumer to customize whether animations apply when the above two methods are called internally.  But I don't know what animations those methods control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `animated` in `UICollectionView`'s `selectItem(at:animated:scrollPosition:)` determines whether the item to-be-selected, if not in view or at required position already, should be scrolled to in an animated fashion or not.
If it's in view then this `animated` property doesn't really do anything, afaik.
Same for the `animated` in `deselectItem(at:animated:)`. It doesn't do anything and is simply there.

The only thing I see affecting the layout engine is if the `collectionView` scrolls and you have animations in the `didSelectItemAt` then it will render these animations ineffective. You would have to delay the animations occurring in the cell (see last example in this answer)

---

As you already know but for others, if you want to animate the cell selection event then you will have to do it yourself in the `collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)` delegate.

Example:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

    //Briefly fade the cell on selection
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
                   animations: {
                    //Fade-out
                    cell?.alpha = 0.5
    }) { (completed) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
                       animations: {
                        //Fade-out
                        cell?.alpha = 1
        })
    }

}
```

---

The above is fine if the user taps on a cell but if you programmatically call `selectItem(at:animated:scrollPosition:)`, it won't trigger the above `collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)` delegate and you would need to explicitly call it to run your selection animation.

Example (Add-on to previous):

```
func doSelect(for aCollectionView: UICollectionView,
              at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    aCollectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath,
                               animated: true,
                               scrollPosition: .centeredVertically)

    //DispatchQueue after sometime because scroll animation renders
    //the animation block in `collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)` ineffective
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.27) { [weak self] in
        self?.collectionView(aCollectionView,
                             didSelectItemAt: indexPath)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was passing `[]` to `scrollPosition` so I didn't notice any changes when I switched the `animated` argument. I assumed it affected some selection animation. Didn't occur to me that it actually animates the scrolling.

Comment: @Hash88 hah, happens. but I am glad to have helped in some way atleast :)

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest overriding `isHighlighted` property of `UICollectionViewCell` with animation. That way if a user taps on a cell and stops to think what to do next, the animation state will be preserved.

```
    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            toggleIsHighlighted()
        }
    }

    func toggleIsHighlighted() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
            self.alpha = self.isHighlighted ? 0.9 : 1.0
            self.transform = self.isHighlighted ?
                CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 0.97, y: 0.97) :
                CGAffineTransform.identity
        })
    }
```